# Why do all the resulting curves from my function combining N-many random ReLUs look like quadratics?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, mathematics, fastai

I've written a function that generates a sum of N-many RelU functions, with random slopes and activation points.

I was expecting these resulting functions to be arbitrary, random curves, but for some reason they all look like a quadratic. Why is that?

Here's my code and an example plot

```py
# Write a function that returns N-Many RelUs
def n_relu(*args, x):
    return sum(F.relu(a*(x+b) + c) for a, b, c in args)

# Intantiate a n_relu function with N random parameter pairs
def instantiate_n_relu(N):
    # Generate N random parameter pairs
    random_parameters = [(random.uniform(-100, 100), random.uniform(-100, 100), random.uniform(-100, 100)) for _ in range(N)]
    
    # Create and return the n_relu function with the random parameters
    return lambda x: n_relu(*random_parameters, x=x)

# Example usage:
N = 100  # Set the desired number of ReLUs

# Instantiate n_relu function with N random parameter pairs
random_n_relu = instantiate_n_relu(N)

def plot_n_relu(f):
    x_values = torch.linspace(-100, 100, 100)
    y_values = f(x_values)

    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.scatter(x_values, y_values, label='N ReLUs')
    plt.title('n_relu Function with N Random Parameter Pairs')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.legend()

plot_n_relu(random_n_relu)
```

[image]

Comment: This may be reformulated as what distribution does $\sum_{a,b,c\sim U(-100, 100)} ReLU(ax + a b + c)$ follow. Therefore, the key of this problem is how the addition and multiplication of uniform random distributions behave. The addition of independent uniform distributions follow a [Irwin–Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution), whose probability density function has polynomials in it.

Comment: The [PDF of the product of two independent uniforms](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/659254/292737) is even mode complicated, involving integrals. So, why does the resulting curve have this look? No idea, but it is not strange giving the complicated forms of the probability density functions their constituent elements have.